# hash on large set of values, retaining information about sequence and approximate size: via Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, hash

In Excel, I have two large columns of values that are usually identical in size and sequence.  I want a hash for each column to check that the columns are in fact identical (with pretty good probability).

I have an MD5 hash algorithm which gives a has for a single string, but I want something for a large (about 20k) set of values).  This would be slow.

I can use a simple function like this:
hash =  mean + stdev + skewness
In VBA, this looks like:

```
    Function hash(x As Range)
    Application.Volatile
    hash = Application.WorksheetFunction.StDev(x) + Application.WorksheetFunction.Skew(x) + Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(x)
    End Function
```

and this gives me some confidence that the columns are the same in terms of magnitudes; but sometimes the values are identical but not in the correct order, and my hash cannot detect this.  I need my hash to be able to detect wrong ordering.

I do not require 'anonymizing' or 'randomizing' of the data- there is no issue of privacy etc.  In fact, a kind of 'proportional' hash that returns a small value for small errors and a large value for large errors would be extremely useful.  Given that some rounding errors may result in small differences that I do not care about, the MD5 algorithm sometimes gives me false warnings.

Unfortunately the data is within excel (because it is the result of previous excel manipulations), and so a VBA function that would keep me in Excel, and allow me to proceed once the columns have been verified,  would be best.  So I'd like a function of the form

Of course, I could just compare the excel columns by making another column, and perform a large boolean AND (cellA1 =cellB1, cellA2=B2) etc.  But this would be tedious and inefficient.  I actually have thousands of these columns to compare in order to find bugs.

Any ideas?

Comment: Read each into an array and loop through the elements to compare. Should be pretty fast.

Comment: Just check if `SUMXMY2(A1:A20000,B1:B20000) < tol` (where `tol` is chosen by your needs). This will be very fast.

Comment: @JohnColeman *very* fast trumps *pretty* fast, lol.

Comment: @BigBen More to the point, compiled C code running under the hood trumps interpreted VBA. Either approach would make more sense than computing and comparing hashes.

Comment: I completely agree. Thanks for teaching me a new formula, hadn't used that one before. Up to you, but if you add as an answer I'll definitely upvote.

Comment: @JohnColeman do you want to put this as an answer for me to tick?  It works well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to compare two columns for near-equality is to use the worksheet function [SUMXMY2()](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMXMY2-function-9D144AC1-4D79-43DE-B524-E2ECEE23B299). This computes the squared-Euclidean distance between two ranges, thought of as vectors in higher-dimensional space. For example, to check if `A1:A20000` is very close to `B1:B20000`, us the comparison

```
SUMXMY2(A1:A20000, B1:B20000) < tol
```

where `tol` is an error threshold which determines how much round-off error you are willing to tolerate.

Your original idea of using hashing could be useful in some circumstances. To make it tolerant of round-off error, look into the theory of [Locality-sensitive hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality-sensitive_hashing) rather than cryptographical hashes such as MD5. Any such algorithm if implemented in VBA would be somewhat slow, but depending on what you are trying to do they could be useful.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer, upvoted as promised.